# Force Talend to use UTC for Dates

Tags: talend, utc

I have a set of dates stored as UTC in my database, when I import them in Salesforce using the tSalesforceOutput:

1. If I run the import from my machine, they get the wrong timezone
2. If I run the import from a server which is in UTC, they get the correct timezone.

Is Talend/Salesforce API using the local timezone? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce will allways convert datetime from user timezone to UTC before to store them.
To avoid any problem, the simpler is to fix the user timezone used for the Salesforce connection to GMT and to explicitly convert each datetime to this timezone before to call any tSalesforceOutputXxxx component.

Here is a routine you can use for this purpose:

```
package routines;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class dateConversion {

    public static String convertToGmt(String strDate, String timezone) throws Exception
    {
        if (strDate == null || timezone == null)
            return null;

        // Convert strDate from any valid TimeZone such as Europe/Paris to GMT
        // strDate is expected to be formatted as "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"
        SimpleDateFormat indfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        indfm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
        Date inDate = indfm.parse(strDate);

        SimpleDateFormat outdfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        outdfm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        String s = outdfm.format(inDate);
        return s;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

TRF

Comment: I am never really dealing with strings. I get a java.util.Date() from the DB and I have a java.util.Date() on the side of the tMap that goes towards Salesforce so I don't understand how to use this function. I will have to perform a Date -> String -> String to get the conversion working and retrieve the current timezone to pass it to convertToGmt?

Comment: You may try to force the timezone at the JVM level passing -Duser.timezone="UTC" on the command line or as a specific JVM argument (tab Run > Advanced settings).

Comment: I would like my job to work correctly in any timezone, not forcing my program to be executed in a specific timezone

Comment: If you want to use the routine you need to retrieve the timezone from which the date conversion then in tMap just write something like dateConversion.convertToGmt(yourDate, yourTZ). This is a method I used for data migration process where TZ was varying for each record depending on it's owner.

Comment: my date on the left side of the tMap comes from MySQL, where it is stored in UTC. I wonder where the conversion happens, is MYSQL Talend Component?

Comment: You may convert during the select or in tMap adding an intermediate Var (have a look to Date.toString() to achieve the conversion). Sorry, I use my phone to answer and not able to make a full example at this time.